# Isometry between Minkowski space and Tangent space in an article by Stefan Waldmann

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, isometries

In the notes  [Geometric Wave Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706) by Stefan Waldmann at   page 70  they have

> Having a fixed Lorentz metric $g$ on a spacetime manifold $M$ we can
> now transfer the notions of special relativity, see e.g. 50 , to $(M,
>  g)$. In fact, each tangent space $\left(T_{p} M, g_{p}\right)$ is
> isometrically isomorphic to Minkowski spacetime $\left(\mathbb{R}^{n},
> \eta\right)$ with $\eta=\operatorname{diag}(+1,-1, \ldots,-1)$, by
> choosing a Lorentz frame: there exist tangent vectors $e_{i} \in T_{p}
>  M$ with $i=1, \ldots, n$ such that $$ g_{p}\left(e_{i},
>  e_{j}\right)=\eta_{i j}=\pm \delta_{i j} . $$

We say that two manifolds $M$ and $N$ are isometric if for all  $v \in T_pM$ and a map $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ such that

$g(v,v)=g'(\phi_*v,\phi_*v)$ where $g$ is a metric in $M$ ,  $g'$ is a metric in $N$ and $\phi_*$ denotes a pushfoward.

Now the definition of isometry  refers  to two manifolds, but in the notes they are claiming an isometry between a manifold and a tangent space.

How can a tangent space be isometric to a manifold?

Comment: The notes you refer to are stating that the **tangent spaces** of the Lorentz manifold are isometric to **Lorentz space** i.e.  this is an isometry of vector spaces with bilinear forms.   The definition isn't constructing them, this is basically part of the definition of a Lorentz manifold.

Comment: @Ryan Budney the notes are saying that tangent space are isometric to Minkosky manifold.

Comment: Not the definition above.

Comment: Minkowski space is a vector space with a bilinear form that has signature $(+1,-1,\dots,-1)$. Given any two such spaces, there is a linear isometry between the two. Each tangent space of $M$ is a vector space. A Lorentz metric assigns to each tangent space $T_pM$ a bilinear form with signature $(+1,-1,\dots,-1)$. Therefore, on a Lorentz manifold, there is an isometry from Minkowski space to $T_pM$.

Comment: It is not standard (and confusing) to write $\phi^*$ for something called a puhsforward... You'd rather want to write $\phi_*$ for the puhsforward (then $\phi^*g'=g$, with $\phi^*g'(u,v):=g'(\phi_*u,\phi_*v)$).

Comment: Asked and answered (with the answer accepted by the OP) here:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709181/isometry-between-minkowski-space-and-tangent-space#comment1586405_709181 .  That accepted answer was posted seven hours before the OP re-posted the same question here.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg thanks for the noticing this. It is very surprising. I don't understand the goal of the OP then.

Comment: @DamienC  Posted the question here because I am searching for different point of vue.  As you  can see  the answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709181/isometry-between-minkowski-space-and-tangent-space#comment1586405_709181 is different from yours

Comment: If we consider $R^n$ only as a manifold is the answer in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709181/isometry-between-minkowski-space-and-tangent-space#comment1586405_709181 that is correct ....

Comment: If we consider $R^n$ as a vector space is your answer wich is correct.

Comment: The two answers are essentially equivalent.

Comment: @DamienC  if we consider  Minkowski as vector space  the metric $\eta$ is acting in the Minkoski space. If we consider it as a manifold it is acting on the tangent space

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused by two different uses for the word "isometry".

There is first the notion of a linear isometry between vector spaces equipped with a non-degenerate bilinear form. This is the notion that is used on page 70 of the paper you refer to. It simply says that, for a Lorentz metric $g$ on a manifold $M$, for every $m\in M$ the tangent space $(T_mM,g)$ is linearly isometric to the Minskowsky space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\eta)$.

There is then the notion of an isometry between two pseudo-riemannian manifolds, that is a smooth map $\phi:M\to N$ such that for every $m\in M$ the tangent map $d\phi_m:T_mM\to T_{\phi(m)}N$ is a linear isometry.

Comment: At page 64 example 2.1.22 he defined Minskowsky spacetime as a manifold not as vector space.

Comment: @amiltonmoreira would you refuse to consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space because several pages before it had been considered as a manifold? Every finite dimensional vector space equipped with a nondegenerate pairing is an example of a pseudo-riemannian manifold. Example 2.1.22 of loc.cit. essentially says this (it is even written "constant metric", with "constant" emphazised).

Comment: $R^n$ can be a manifold without being a vector space

Comment: A manifold is something that locally looks like a finite dimensional R-vector space. As such, any finite dimensional R-vector space is a manifold. I don't understand what you don't understand.